# Regex - selecting an additional character incorrectly

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/(^|[^\\])"/g
```

With the above JavaScript regex, it is meant to only match " if there is no \". This works fine but it is selecting one character too many.

So if I have the string A"B, it is selecting A", but should only select " .

If I have A\"B - it isn't selecting anything (which is correct).

But if I have A"B, it should only select " .

Comment: I am replacing this with /" if it matches.

Comment: `[^\\]` will capture 1 character

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am writing a script that escapes all double quotes unless they are already escaped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(^|[^\\])"
```

You can use this and replace by `$1/"`.Because javascript does not have lookbehind you will have to replace by `$1` whatever is captured before `"`.This single character is being captured by `[^\\]`

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/yM4oD2/1)

```
var re = /(^|[^\\])"/g; 
var str = 'A\"B\nA"B,\n';
var subst = '$1/"'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 1):

`([^\\])` captures one character that is not a backslash.

You could simply make this group a non-capturing group:

```
/(?:^|[^\\])"/g
```

And then you could enclose the quotation mark in a group:

```
/(?:^|[^\\])(")/g
```

Now your `"` ends up in match group 1.